# How to pass the sanitizer blacklist from clang when compiling LLVM IR?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, llvm

I have a question when using dfsan via clang. Blacklist doesn't work.

```
clang -S -emit-llvm main.c  
clang -S -emit-llvm -fsanitize=dataflow main.ll
```

DFsan changed the name of main function to `dfs$main`. In fact, main is in the blacklist, and the main function should not be changed.
But when I use `-fsanitize=dataflow` to main.c source file directly, default blacklist works. The name of main function is skipped.

```
Clang -S -emit llvm -fsanitize=dataflow main.c
```

the blacklist works, and the main function is not modified.
It also works with opt.

```
opt -dfsan -dfsan-abilist="the_list.txt"
```

In the construction of DataFlowSanitizer, I find that there is no blacklist-file path passed into it.

Did I miss some options when I use dfsan from clang ?
I mean :

```
clang -fsanitize=dataflow main.ll （instead of main.c）
```

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding option for clang invocations is `-fsanitize-blacklist`:

```
clang -fsanitize=dataflow -fsanitize-blacklist=file.txt
```

Relevant documentation: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerSpecialCaseList.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I tried it, the blacklist still didnot work. It still modified the name of main function. What I did is clang to the LLVM IR like this:  clang -S -emit-llvm -fsanitize=dataflow -fsanitize-blacklist=file.txt  main.ll . It seems to be a bug in clang?